# getConfirmedTransaction return error Transaction version (0) is not supported by the requesting client

Tags: transactions, transaction-instructions

I am getting an error for these transactions:

```
3D5pNo4kAC3LRJi5JyVMiCBAhj1DKeujsfS7q2rvQwXX7kkUVPZX9j2wHVHDjpwhNPYH75fEPWThw8a7SG84pH8E
4xfwN51GFa85C1okPCR9oGKzm9kM8XFg1jNJVeL26RAmnZifyk3LaG2Q2ykEQt2csUeST4Y88iX5rjqRLwKyAj5E
36KhL9wXQJeTV7AGWA8GaPBPSpw26oZjMc2kvEUuFxGmksxTNik9TiCbk19AWoSo9cdC1Xtv8N7nys3MmraPMFSA
5c9K7hiR1xk86wwq1dBYtts6rnhGbwgR3vaoLKJzR7PYmnFK5yzUvHx2Z3QvjLoVUQBzeUdJPywneeSAKxpCESCi
2hnadqANB8m4J4trXeQmRd2DnDeuazhk9o8G3jcYbc85xNUeKxDLbCXZ3dq1kK1rYMELX4sDNty3Uf7zhyqcLRoH
```

curl -

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/'
--header 'Content-Type: application/json'
--data-raw '{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 1,
  "method": "getConfirmedTransaction",
  "params": [
    "5HbX6YFiQJsUhG1RM6YN8KNNY86rEpRJpG9WUWJmirAeiby5B6b6nH5qK43xctCxhecLKCmdKzuA1uFqFrLMfALg",
    "json"
  ]
}
'
o/p -
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "error": {
    "code": -32015,
    "message": "Transaction version (0) is not supported by the requesting client. Please try the request again with the following configuration parameter: "maxSupportedTransactionVersion": 0"
  },
  "id": 1
}
```

Thanks
Umang Awasthy

Answer (score 4):

Be sure to add the `"maxSupportedTransactionVersion"` param to your call to correctly get v0 transactions.  That means doing:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw \
' { "jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "getConfirmedTransaction", "params": ["5HbX6YFiQJsUhG1RM6YN8KNNY86rEpRJpG9WUWJmirAeiby5B6b6nH5qK43xctCxhecLKCmdKzuA1uFqFrLMfALg", {"encoding: "json", "maxSupportedTransactionVersion":0} ] }
```

Sorry for the rough formatting, but that should do it! You can learn more about the optional parameters at https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettransaction

Answer (score 4):

For web3.js users:

```
await connection.getParsedTransactions(signatures, {
  maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0,
});
```

See https://docs.solana.com/developing/versioned-transactions for information on transaction versions.